# can a div stretch outside of a scroll box?

Tags: css, html, scroll

In my current markup, I have two scroll boxes in the dashboard div. I want the gray highlight around the selected task to stretch and meet the highlight around the info box to it's right. Is there a way to do that?

http://jsfiddle.net/rEKwb/2/

Thanks!

edit:
OK, this is what it looks like now. 
http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v410/justice4all_quiet/what_it_do.jpg

The gray box around the green box is cut off. I'd like it to stretch to meet the gray border to the right of it, which is in a separate scroll box.

This is what I want it to look like.
http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v410/justice4all_quiet/example.jpg

Comment: Hello, Shvelo. I updated the post so hopefully it makes a little more sense.

Comment: Have you tried negative left and right margin?

Comment: Yeah, a negative margin just moves it over inside of the scroll box. So it moves and gets cut off instead of moving outside of the box.

Answer (score 0):

I think because you have your `<section id="tasks">` with a style of `overflow: scroll;` it will create a horizontal scroll bar if you try and stretch the `<div id="selected_task">` beyond its parents defined width.  Basically you can't have elements that are within a `overflow: scroll;` ignore the scroll rule and render outside of the box... it will always create horizontal scroll bar to manage the extended content.

A workaround may be to use a [jQuery scroll bar plugin](http://www.net-kit.com/jquery-custom-scrollbar-plugins/) and play with `position:relative` and `z-index` values of your divs sense these plugins usuall use a combination of divs to create their scroll bars and not the browsers scroll bar.

Comment: You're right, there's probably not an easy CSS/HTML solution to this. I haven't dabbled in JavaScript or jQuery just yet so I guess it's time I do.

Answer (score 0):

There is always the space for the scrollbar, even if its not in use. 
If you can force the scrollbar to the left, you will get rid of the gap on the right.

You can try changing text direction, to force the scrollbar to the left:

```
direction: rtl;
```

Comment: That makes it do this: http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v410/justice4all_quiet/new_do.jpg